# PHP mysql_query login system security

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making a login system (and really new at php). My friend has told me that I'd be better off using PDO. However, I have no idea how to use PDO and I'm already a bit familiar with MySQL. For instance, here is a part of my code:

```
$un = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i','',$_POST['username']);
$pw = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i','',$_POST['password']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `username`,`password` FROM `login` where `username` = $un && `password` = $pw") or die (mysql_error());
```

Would the above code have any type of security risk, since all non alphanumerical characters are being stripped? If so, what is the best approach to this? (using either PDO or raw MySQL)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than guessing at ReqExp's and/or restricting the allowed characters, you can just use `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `username`,`password`
                       FROM `login` 
                       WHERE `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' &&
                             `password` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'")
```

Comment: Can absolutely nothing else be done to perform some type of MySQL injection? What security precautions should I take?

Comment: @Howard That's the nice thing about `mysql_real_escape_string` [in conjunction with string quoting], you can rest assured there won't be injection.

Answer (score 0):

That should be sufficient in sanitizing your login, but it limits your username/passwords to only alpha's. Better would be `/[^a-z0-9-_\s]|^\s|\s$|[^0-9a-zA-Z-_](?=\s)/i`

That is `a-z,0-9,-,-,and space`. Removes space at the beginning of the string and at the end, and any space that follows any character other than `a-z,0-9,-,_`